Consistency of a set of well-founded sets that is not well-founded
In the proof that
$U=V \leftrightarrow Foundation$, the $\rightarrow$ direction can be easily shown by considering $grounded$ sets ($x$ is grounded iff $\forall y: x \in y \rightarrow (y$ is well-founded)), observing that any set of grounded sets is itself grounded and then using transfinite induction to show that all members of the $V_\alpha$ are grounded. While there are other proofs using a detour through epsilon induction and a clever argument by applying epsilon-induction to certain formulas, the easiest proof idea seems to me to be to apply epsilon induction (or transfinite induction on the $V_\alpha$) to the property 'x is well-founded'. ('well-founded' meaning $x$ has an $\in$-minimal element, although as pointed out in the comments a better definition might be '$\in$ is a well-founded relation on x' so that not every set containing the empty set is well-founded) Issue is I cannot make it work and have found no resources online to show that a set of well-founded sets is well-founded (in $ZF^-$ or $ZFC^-$). So my question is twofold:
Does anyone know of a proof of the statement and if not, is it independent of $ZF^-$ or $ZFC^-$?
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

What definition of a set $x$ being well-founded are you using? (In any event the statement in question is provable in $\sf ZF^-$, provided the definition is equivalent to $x\in V$ over $\sf ZF^-$ (which it should be) since it's easy to see a set of sets in $V$ is in $V$, but how to directly prove the statement depends on the precise definition, of course.)

I guess my "which is should be" is doing some heavy lifting there since perhaps the most obvious definition "$\in$ is a well-founded relation on $x$" isn't equivalent to $x\in V$... which I would argue makes it the "wrong" definition. (And a set of sets with that property doesn't necessarily have that property.)

@spaceisdarkgreen By well-founded I mean having an $\in$-minimal element, i.e. the axiom of foundation (in its common form) holds for that set. This I think is even weaker than saying '$\in$ is a well founded relation on x'. That the statement holds for your definition makes sense, but I don't think the two definitions are equivalent over $ZF^-$, although I'm not sure.

Yeah, that's not the "correct" definition of well-founded and under that definition it's not the case that a set of well-founded sets is necessarily well-founded. Consider a "double-Quine", which is known to be consistent with $\sf ZFC^-$, i.e. sets $a\ne b$ such that $a = {b}$ and $b= {a}.$ Then $a$ and $b$ are "well-founded", but ${a,b}$ is not. (One close "correct" definition is that a set is well-founded if $\in$ is a well-founded relation on its transitive closure.)

And note that the same counterexample applies to the stronger "$\in$ is well-founded on $x$"... the transitive closure part is necessary.
